# Creating dynamic select boxes from jsVanilla

Tags: javascript, json, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying to create few dynamic select boxes with vanila JavaScript. As you can see below I use json object with nested nodes for each select box as an option.

I have problem with creating for loop with nested json object.

```
"use strict"

let vars = {

  kagit: {
    abr: "",
    krome: 1,
    fantezi: 6,
    kraft: 5,
    hamur: 4
   },
  ebat: {
    elli: 5,
    yetmis: 76
  },
  laminasyon:{
    parlak:7,
    mat:7
  },
  ondule:{
    bst: 88,
    tst: 0,
    dopez: 7
  },
  kesim:{
    bobst:4,
    pedal:7
  }

}

let optKagit = document.querySelector('.kagit');

let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
defaultOption.text = 'Lütfen Seçiniz';

optKagit.add(defaultOption);
optKagit.selectedIndex = 0;

let option;
    for (let i = 0; i < vars.kagit.length; i++) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = vars.kagit[i];
      option.value = vars.kagit[i][""];
      optKagit.add(option);
    }
```

Here is the html code

```
<select name="kagit" class="kagit">
      </select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eg145y7o/1/

Comment: kagit is an object not an array. You can use Object.keys to iterate over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer after Christoph Lütjen's clue.

```
let option;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(vars.kagit)) {
  option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = key;
  option.value = value;
  optKagit.add(option);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample with "for in" on "vars.kagit":

```
for (var i in vars.kagit) {
    console.log(i, vars.kagit[i]);
}
```

Sample with "Object.keys" on every vars:

```
for (let i = 0, j = Object.keys(vars), k = j.length; i < k; i++) {
    let iVar = vars[j[i]];
    // and "for in" on each var
    for (let l in iVar) {
        console.log(l, iVar);
    }
}
```